# Selecting attribute values into a List<string>

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML, I need to be able to get the name of the users in the Household_Services category.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <category id="Household_Services">
    <users>
      <add name="ESB"/>
      <add name="BordGais"/>
      <add name="Eircom"/>
    </users>
  </category>
  <category id="Financial_Accounts">
    <users>
      <add name="BankOfIreland"/>
      <add name="AIB"/>
    </users>
  </category>
  <category id="Health_Records">
    <users>
      <add name="VHI"/>
      <add name="IrishLife"/>
    </users>
  </category>
</root>
```

The closest I can get is

```
string category = "Household_Services";

var users = from n in xe.Elements("category")
            where (string)n.Attribute("id") == category
            select n.Element("users").Elements("add").Attributes("name");
```

This gives me an `IEnumerable<XAttribute>` but what I need is a `List<string>`.

Any ideas what I need to change?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line

```
select n.Element("users").Elements("add").Attributes("name");
```

to

```
select n.Element("users").Elements("add").Attributes("name").Select(a => a.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the Value Property of your XAttribute.

either

```
var attributes = from n in xe.Elements("category")
        where (string)n.Attribute("id") == category
        from attribute in n.Element("users").Elements("add").Attributes("name")
        select attribute.Value
var users = attributes.Select(x => x.Value);
```

or

```
var users = from n in xe.Elements("category")
        where (string)n.Attribute("id") == category
        from attribute in n.Element("users").Elements("add").Attributes("name")
        select attribute.Value
```

would to the trick.